# Are the groups $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic under addition?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, group-isomorphism

Are the groups $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic under addition?

Comment: They are even isomorphic as real vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Under the usual definition of $(\mathbb{C},+)$, they are isomorphic by definition. That's because the usual definition is:

- $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$;
- the addition in $\mathbb C$ is the same as in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: This might be why I didn't see anywhere in my book plainly written they are isomorphic. It must have been implied by definition. Thx